# Android. How to send data to developer server

Tags: android

I have an app with a simple textbox and a button . A click on the button should send the user entered data to a development server. I need help in choosing and setting up the development server and a way to send my data to the development server.

Comment: u should google "how to send data from android to server"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @balaRaja You Should Probably familiar with the Webhosting, database, CRUD operations, RESTful WebServices.

Here are some tips

## 1 .Database Design

the data  will be used to store data

## 2 Write web services

Your app is going to call this service by sending the data as Post data And this will be Pushed up to the DB

## 3 Deploy On Webserver

use any free web hosting Providers  like [000 Webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/)

## 4 Call web service from App

With in the App When you clikc the send button invoke the Webservice by passing the Input data as arguments

for Detailed info : [CRUD Operation in Android](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I will try it.